# Google maps get location address from file_get_contents with json

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I m getting latitude and longitude by doing the following. Can I get the address also?. If yes, please someone help me to modify the below piece of code to get address also with the lat and long.

```
$zipcode= 10003;
$json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$zipcode&sensor=false");
$json = json_decode($json);
$lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can get formated adress from the response :

```
$address = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'formatted_address'};
```

You can also get each component separately :

```
$zipcode    = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'address_components'}[0]->{'long_name'};
$city       = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'address_components'}[1]->{'long_name'};
$department = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'address_components'}[2]->{'long_name'};
$region     = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'address_components'}[3]->{'long_name'};
$country    = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'address_components'}[4]->{'long_name'};
```